# Steam reads registry key constantly

Tags: windows-registry, steam

I currently noticed high hard drive activity and looked into it using [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).

I found out that Steam is constantly trying to read the same key without success and doesn't stop, even after hours.

I contacted Steam support and followed all the steps proposed by the support guy, but nothing helped. I did a complete uninstall of the program, manually deleted remaining folders, deleted the appropriate registry keys and even used one of those strange FixIt programs by Microsoft.

It's not really slowing down my computer but it's causing very much had drive traffic and obviously an abnormal behavior. Has anyone faced the same problem before?

My system is Windows 8 x64 and I used the latest version of Steam.

Screenshot of procmon:

[image]

**UPDATE**
In the meantime I re-installed Windows on new hardware... and the problem persists. This drives my crazy.

Comment: Have you tried a full uninstall/reinstall yet?

Comment: Sorry, but have you read the text I wrote? I did a complete uninstall, even checked that there were no traces left in the registry.

Comment: Sorry missed that paragraph, was reading on my phone

Comment: Manually modify the permissions to that registry key.  Otherwise report the obvious bug to Steam.

Comment: How do I modify registry key access permissions? I already reported the bug, they just advised me to uninstall/reinstall...